# Write a file in a folder with dynamic path C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, ofstream

I successfully write to a file in the folder which run example:

```
// I run "test" executable file in "TestWrite File" folder
const char *path="/home/kingfisher/Desktop/TestWrite File/xml/kingfisher.txt";
std::ofstream file(path); //open in constructor
std::string data("data to write to file");
file << data;
```

However, If I try to write with dynamic path: `*path = "/xml/kingfisher.txt"`, it goes wrong (in `Windows`, it will be fine)!! How I can write with dynamic path like above (not a specific path)? Thanks!

Comment: By wrong, do you mean it fails to open the file? The directory `/xml` may not exist and the `ofstream` constructor does not create missing directories.

Comment: "goes wrong"..? And what do you mean "dynamic path"? Maybe you meant to leave out the `/` before the `x` and call it a relative path, in which case you probably aren't in the working directory that you think you are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by "dynamic path"; a dynamic path is one that
will be read dynamically (and so will probably be in an `std::string`).

On the other hand, you seem to be confusing absolute path and relative
path.  If the filename begins with a `'/'` (under Unix), or with a `'/'`
or a `'\\'`, possibly preceded by `"d:"` under
Windows, it is absolute; the search for the file will start at the root
of the file system (on the specified drive in the case of Windows).  In
all other cases, it is relative; the search for the file will start at
the current working directory.  In your example, both
`"/home/kingfisher/Desktop/TestWrite File/xml/kingfiger.txt"` and
`"/xml/kingfisher.txt"` are absolute.  If the current working directory
is `"/home/kingfisher/Desktop/TestWrite File"`, then
`"xml/kingfisher.txt"` should find the file specified by the first
absolute pathname.

Answer (score 3):

If by dynamic you mean relative, you need to get rid of the leading `/`, since that makes it an absolute path:

```
path = "xml/kingfisher.txt";
```

Just be aware that this file is relative to your current working directory so you will probably need to ensure that it is set to `/home/kingfisher/Desktop/TestWrite File` for this to work.

If, by dynamic, you mean *changable,* you can change it whenever you want:

```
const char *path = "/tmp/dummy";
:
path = "/home/.profile";          // Note path, NOT *path
```

The `const` simply means you're not permitted to change the data *behind* the pointer. You're able to change the pointer itself at will.

Answer (score 1):

```
*path = "/xml/kingfisher.txt"
```

This is incorrect since it attempts to dereferences your `const char*` and modify the contents.  This is undefined behaviour since the data is const.

Just declare your path to be a `std::string` to begin with:

```
std::string path = "/home/kingfisher/Desktop/TestWrite File/xml/kingfisher.txt";
```

Then later you can assign any other value you like to the std string and it's `operator=` will dynamically change it's internals for you:

```
path = "my/new/path";
```

You can use this with `ofstream` just as before and if you need to pass it to a function which expects a `const char *` just pass `path.c_str()`.

Comment: _"This is incorrect since it dereferences your char* and sets the first character in your original string"_ - actually it's a `char const*` and doesn't set anything to anything except setting the "Undefined Behaviour"-ness flag to "true"

Comment: @paxdiablo I actually thought `const char *` and `char const *` were the same thing.  It's `char * const` which is a constant pointer to variable data.